# How can I measure the size of the object I send over RMI?

Tags: java, performance, rmi

I'm doing some performance tuning on my application and would like to know a good way of measuring the size of the object that I am sending over RMI.

The aim is to make my object leaner.

Comment: One way of making your object leaner is to use enumerations for commonly used strings. Make sure that you also use transient for fields you don't want serialising. Write your own readObject/writeObjects and implement a versioning system as well.

Comment: @FortyRunner That doesn't change anything. Enums are serialized as their own names, which are strings. Writing your own `read/writeObject()` methods may or may not help, and custom versioning certainly won't. And versioning is already built in. Your recommendations are just make-work.

Comment: Should have been clearer: Using a custom writeobject - send an integer across, the readObject just needs to rehydrate from the integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest way to do this is to put in some test code which writes the object to a file.  then, look at the size of the file.

or, if you don't want to write to disk (and your objects are not going to blow out memory):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bout);
oos.writeObject(theObjectIWantTheSizeOf);
oos.close();
System.out.println("The object size is: " + bout.toByteArray().length:
```

Comment: This is not enough - the class may be sent as well as the serialized form of its instance.

Comment: @McDowell That's not correct. Classes are not serialized.

Answer (score 0):

Because your object is serializable already - you can use the size() method on ObjectOutputStream to do this.

Comment: There is no size method on ObjectOutputStream - you might want to clarify what you mean.

Comment: I meant on ByteArrayOutputStream - thanks for the correction.

Comment: Alas, looking into it, this mechanism is not reliable - see my post.

Answer (score 0):

> This is not enough - the class may be sent as well as the serialized form of its instance.

The class should only be sent once and it will be the size it is on disk.
Are you only sending the object once, or many times? If the latter the size of the class shouldn't be important.

Comment: Classes are not serialized at all, contrary to the erroneous statement you quote.

Comment: @EJP the byte code for a class can be transferred depending on how RMI is setup.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check first what RMI protocol you are using. If you are using **EJB 3** it might be calling CORBA (RMI-IIOP). If you want to improve the performance you can use the RMI over - Zipped IOP (**ZIOP**) — A zipped version of GIOP that reduces the bandwidth usage. try http://docs.jboss.org/jbossremoting/2.5.2.SP2/html_single/

Answer (score -1):

A few month ago, I found this article [Instrumentation Memory Counter](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue142.html) at the [Javaspecialist](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/) site, about calculating memory usage of Java objects. Perhaps it could be helpful for you.